# primeng autocomplete not showing results after angular upgrade

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm not sure that it was the upgrade from Angular 2 to Angular 4 that did it, but I haven't really touched that code this whole time in any other way.

```
  <p-autoComplete placeholder="Search by organization name" size="30" [(ngModel)]="autocompleteValue" (onSelect)="captureEvent($event);gotoLink($event.link)" [field]="title" [suggestions]="foundItems" (completeMethod)="search($event)">
    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="foundItems">
        <div >{{item.title}}</div>
    </ng-template>
  </p-autoComplete>
```

The function that finds the results via API, "search", is working fine. The array in the *this* scope that holds those results is also working fine as I see by logging it to the console. It's just not appearing as a list of items below the search box, and there's no error.

An example of the running app can be seen [here](https://dev.probono.net/georgiaadvocates/atlanta/oppsguide/).

The search method shown in the p-autoComplete tag is this (where `this.organizationService.searchNames` is an api call. That API call is correctly returning the right data):

```
search(event): void {
this.foundItems = [];
let areasOfLawFilter = this.prepareCategoryFilter( this.getMenuWithCategory("Area of Law"), this.selectedMenuItems );
let workingWithFilter = this.prepareCategoryFilter( this.getMenuWithCategory("Working with"), this.selectedMenuItems );
let opportunitiesForFilter = this.prepareCategoryFilter( this.getMenuWithCategory("Opportunities for"), this.selectedMenuItems );
let countiesFilter = this.prepareCategoryFilter( this.getMenuWithCategory("Counties"), this.selectedMenuItems );
let regionFilter = this.prepareCategoryFilter( this.getMenuWithCategory("Region served"), this.selectedMenuItems );
this.organizationService.searchNames( this.pageId, this.FEEDSERVER, areasOfLawFilter, workingWithFilter, opportunitiesForFilter, countiesFilter, regionFilter, event.query.toLowerCase() )
.then((data) => { this.foundItems = this.getOrganizationsFromPayload(data); console.log(this.foundItems);})
.then(() => this.setLoaded())
.catch( reason => { console.log(reason) } );
```

}

And `this.getOrganizationsFromPayload(data)` from directly above is

```
private getOrganizationsFromPayload(data: any[]): Organization[] {
let newArray: Organization[] = [];
for (let obj of data) {
  let newObject: Organization = new Organization(
    /*id*/ obj.id,
    /*title*/ obj.name.replace(/&apos;/g,"'"),
    /*contentType*/ 'organization',
    /*description*/ obj.description.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g,""),
    /*descriptionLength*/ obj.descriptionLength || 250,
    /*modifyDate*/ moment(obj.modifyDate).isValid()? moment(obj.modifyDate).toDate(): null,
    /*areaOfLaw*/ this.utilityService.getJSONArray(obj.areaOfLaw),
    /*workingWith*/ this.utilityService.getJSONArray(obj.workingWith),
    /*opportunitiesFor*/ this.utilityService.getJSONArray(obj.opportunitiesFor),
    /*counties*/ this.utilityService.getJSONArray(obj.counties),
    /*numProjects*/ obj.numProjects,
    /*numCases*/ obj.numCases,
    /*isNational*/ obj.isNational === "1"? "National":"Local",
    /*isClicked*/ false,
    /*isCle*/ obj.isCle === "1",
    /*link*/ obj.link,
    /*parentLink*/ obj.link.replace(/\/[^\/]*$/,"")
    );
  newArray.push(newObject);
}
return newArray;
```

}

We know this function is correctly creating the array of foundItems because the console shows:

```
(4) [Organization, Organization, Organization, Organization]
0:Organization {isClicked: false, isCle: false, descriptionLength: 250, id: "375024", title: " ABA Military Pro Bono Project", …}
1:Organization {isClicked: false, isCle: false, descriptionLength: 250, id: "470940", title: " ABA Military Pro Bono Project (Massachusetts)", …}
2:Organization {isClicked: false, isCle: false, descriptionLength: 250, id: "642455", title: " ABA Military Pro Bono Project (New York)", …}
3:Organization {isClicked: false, isCle: false, descriptionLength: 250, id: "466617", title: " ABA/FEMA Disaster Legal Assistance Program - ABA Young Lawyers Division (New York)", …}
```

Each Organization has a `title` property, which is what our ng-template is displaying.

Comment: try to use spread operator to assign your array in this way `foundItems = {...foundItems}`.

Comment: Thanks, but where?

Comment: Can you show the code of the function that is fetching the data in your component?

Comment: Updated with all relevant code. Also will add that I added the BrowserModuleAnimations import, which the PrimeNG spec said might be necessary in Angular 4.

Comment: I attempted to define `this.foundItems = {...this.getOrganizationsFromPayload(data)}` as suggested, but got `ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`, which makes sense. Changing that to `this.foundItems = [...this.getOrganizationsFromPayload(data)]` as you probably meant didn't make a difference (but no error.)

Comment: Well, the foundItems array is there, so I'm just going to include a <ul *ngIf='foundItems.length'> and show the list when it's available. Not sure what pooped in the primeng component.

Comment: I meant recreate the array to trigger change detection as is stated in primeng datatable docs _"DataTable either uses setter based checking or ngDoCheck to realize if the underlying data has changed to update the UI. So **your data changes such as adding or removing a record should always create a new array reference instead of manipulating an existing array as Angular does not trigger setters if the reference does not change.** For example, use slice instead of splice when removing an item or use spread operator instead of push method when adding an item."_

Comment: I see. At the top of the search function, called on keypress, I was setting `this.foundItems = []`. Just to force the issue I tried, `this.foundItems = new Array()`, but that didn't make a difference. In both cases I was later assigning that array to a new array generated from the API.

Comment: odd, that was my last attempt hehehe, hope you resolve this!! success